# How to concatenate three fields in table into one table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to concatenate three fields in my MS Access table into one field by using VBA. How can I do this?

I have tried using query to concatenate it and it works, but I would like it to be concatenated and saved in my table instead.

My 3 fields I want to concatenate into 1 field are: CompanyCode,YearCode and PO number.

Currently my table look like this:

```
Company code           YearCode                PONumber
    ABC                    17/                   200
```

What I want:

```
PONumber 
ABC17/200
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this. [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html) -- You can use the query (with the concatenated fields) wherever you would use the table.

Comment: @Andre Thankyou for replying! Does this mean that it is not possible to have calculated fields in table? even with the help of coding?

Comment: Duplicate / Cross Posted with a ton of advice/ answers here: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=295412

Comment: It *is* possible, but it is a very bad idea. Why do you want to store this in the table?

Comment: Oh my. (runs and hides from this question) @Minty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query:

```
Select *, [Company Code] & [YearCode] & [PONumber] As FullNumber
From YourTable
```

If you insist on having a calculated field in the table itself, use this expression when you - in design view - add the calculated field:

```
[Company Code] & [YearCode] & [PONumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned @Andre, highly not recommended to use calculated fields in Access tables at all, this feature is quite buggy. But in some cases it's reasonable to store combined code in separate regular field for performance improvement, despite this denormalizes the database structure. You can store combined code in form's `BeforeUpdate` event:

```
Me!PONumberFull = Me![Company code] & Me!YearCode & Me!PONumber
```

Also I'd recommend to do not store "/" in YearCode, just number. In this case the code will be

```
Me!PONumberFull = Me![Company code] & Me!YearCode & "/" & Me!PONumber
```